# Search API result get view containing article, not article it self

Tags: views, nodes, search

I am having difficulties with finding view that contains searched text, not article it self. I have a page congaing 2 blocks of views, and would like to get a link to that page. Currently I get search results but link only to article.

How can I get a reference to rendered page from Search API?

Comment: From the user's viewpoint, wouldn't the article page be more relevant to them? Search API does not index views and from a technical perspective it would be hard to make it do so - think about the case where a view has multiple pages and filters, you might need to index hundreds of combinations.

Comment: Hi Alfred, thanks for reply. I understand that article content would be important but would like to move from that cms look and feel. Google search API is indexing rendered pages, would it be possible to do something like that with Search API. Would like to use Solr and be able to return the page it self where content was found. Couldn't find even the way how to identify by content type what views are showing that content type and from there what page has that specific view.

Comment: Google is a completely different thing with hundreds of engineers and thousands of man hours poured into it. It works differently than Solr. The point of any search is to take you to what you are looking for, not another search page of stuff (Views).

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for reply. I was hoping there is a way in search api to achieve the same result from user perspective as Google search api module. If this is not possible do you maybe have some suggestions how to find references between nodes, views and pages. Thanks again.

Comment: @Nenad Google works that way because it does not have any special knowledge of the structure of your content. A local site search can be optimised to get users to the content they want without wading through lists. Search API is actually helping your users by not indexing views.

Comment: Hi Alfred, I agree that search API is more powerful and advance search mechanism. Also the delay of Google search noticing the changes on your website is too long.I was just wondering is there a procedure if someone was using Google api module and would like to migrate to search api without customers noticing any difference. That is what I thought when I said "to achieve the same result from user perspective" in my previous comment. Thanks again for your replies.